# Read file in 8086 until the end of the file

Tags: assembly, x86-16, file-read, emu8086

```
MOV AH,3DH
MOV DX,OFFSET(FNAME)
MOV AL,0  ; 0 MEAN FOR READING PURPOSE             ;OPEN
INT 21H
MOV HANDLE,AX 

MOV AH,3FH
MOV BX,HANDLE
MOV DX,OFFSET(BUFFER)                            ;READ
MOV CX,30
INT 21H

MOV AH,3EH
MOV DX,HANDLE                                     ;CLOSE
INT 21H
```

Now here the program reads only 30 letters from the file. I need is to read the whole file without knowing how many letters in it so how much letter it has the program will read them all.

Comment: And what if the file is so large that it doesn't fit not only in a segment, but even in the whole RAM?..

Comment: No, I need just to like read it 5 bits every time and then this 5 bits send them to another file and re-read another five bits until the end of the file

Comment: On return, AX will contain the number of bytes read ([source](https://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-3f.html)). Typically what you do is allocate an appropriately-sized buffer, read a chunk of the file into the buffer, handle that chunk, and repeat. You know you're done with AX is less than what you asked for.

Comment: \* *when* AX is less than...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> MOV AH,3FH
> MOV BX,HANDLE
> MOV DX,OFFSET(BUFFER)                            ;READ
> MOV CX,30
> INT 21H
> ```

This is the code that you need to replace with a loop that reads successive chunks of the file until there is nothing left.

The 3Fh DOS call not only informs you via the carry flag about possible errors, but it also returns in the `AX` register the number of bytes that were actually read.

```
ReadMore:
    mov dx, offset BUFFER
    mov cx, 5           ; Your chunk apparently has 5 bytes
    mov bx, HANDLE
    mov ah, 3Fh         ; DOS.ReadFile
    int 21h             ; -> AX CF
    jc  ReadError
    cmp ax, cx          ; Compares RECEIVED BYTES with REQUESTED BYTES
    jb  PartialRead
WholeChunk:

    ... Whatever you need to do with 5 bytes ...

    jmp     ReadMore
PartialRead:
    test    ax, ax
    jz      EndOfFile
PartialChunk:

    ... Whatever you can do with 1, 2, 3, or 4 left-over bytes ...

EndOfFile:
    mov bx, HANDLE
    mov ah, 3Eh         ; DOS.CloseFile
    int 21h
    ...
```

Please notice the typo in next snippet. The handle goes in the `BX` register!

> ```
> MOV AH,3EH
> MOV DX,HANDLE                                     ;CLOSE
> INT 21H
> ```